# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle2

I'm using Cycle2 slider with Json. The slider works fine, but I get this error in Google Chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined.

Here's a working Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojavEW

Google Chrome highlights this part of the code:

```
  i.title.$t, l = 0; l < i.link.length; l++)
```

I don't know how to fix it, any suggestions?

```css
.cycle-slideshow .item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 0!important;
  margin: 4px!important;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cycle-slideshow {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.cycle-slideshow img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 450px;
}
.slider-overlay {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: none;
}
.cycle-slideshow .item:hover .slider-overlay {
  display: block;
}
.slider-centered {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 100%;
}
.slide-content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
.slide-content h3,
.slider-sum {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.slider-sum {
  margin: 10px 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.slide-content h3 {
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font: normal normal 30px Oswald;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script style='text/javascript'>
  //<![CDATA[
  function showgalleryposts(t) {
    var e = t.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,
      n = new Array;
    for (var r = 0; e > r; ++r) n[r] = r;
    for (1 == random_posts && n.sort(function() {
      return .5 - Math.random()
    }), numposts_gal > e && (numposts_gal = e), r = 0; numposts_gal > r; ++r) {
      for (var i = t.feed.entry[n[r]], o = i.title.$t, l = 0; l < i.link.length; l++)
        if ("alternate" == i.link[l].rel) {
          posturl_gal = i.link[l].href;
          break
        }
      if (
        "content" in i) var u = i.content.$t;
      if (s = u, a = s.indexOf("<img"), b = s.indexOf('src="', a), c = s.indexOf('"', b + 5), d = s.substr(b + 5, c - b - 5), -1 != a && -1 != b && -1 != c && "" != d) var m = d;
      else var m = "";
      document.write('<div class="item" style="background: url(' + m + ');"><div class="slider-overlay"><div class="slider-centered"><span class="slide-content"><h3 style="margin:10px 0 0;">'), document.write(o + "</h3>");
      var g = /<\S[^>]*>/g;
      if (u = u.replace(g, ""), 1 == showpostsummary_gal)
        if (u.length < numchars_gal) document.write(u), document.write("</span>");
        else {
          u = u.substring(0, numchars_gal);
          var p = u.lastIndexOf(" ");
          u = u.substring(0, p), document.write("<span class='slider-sum'>" + u + "...</span>"), document.write(
            "<span class='slide-more'><a href='" + posturl_gal + "'>Read More</a></span></span></div>")
        }
      document.write('</div>'), document.write("</div>")
    }

  }
  var showpostthumbnails_gal = !0,
    showpostsummary_gal = !0,
    random_posts = !1,
    numchars_gal = 30,
    numposts_gal = 10;
  //]]>
</script>
<div class='cycle-slideshow' data-cycle-fx=carousel data-cycle-timeout=1000 data-cycle-carousel-visible=3 data-cycle-carousel-fluid=true data-cycle-pause-on-hover=true data-cycle-slides='.item'>

  <script src='http://www.thebeautybybel.com/feeds/posts/default?orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showgalleryposts&max-results=6'></script>
</div>
```

Comment: an item in the `t.feed.entry` array does not have a property named `title` - is that possible?

Comment: @JaromandaX It's normal according to this: [Blogger JSON Feed API](http://www.danpros.com/2013/08/blogger-json-feed-api)

Comment: i didn't as what the spec was, check the data - use console.log in your code and developer tools to see the output

Comment: O firefox it keeps saying i is undefined.